# How to daemonise a shell-script in FreeBSD (and macOS)

Tags: macos, shell, daemon, freebsd, darwin

The way I normally start a long-running shell script is

```
% (nohup ./script.sh </dev/null >script.log 2>&1 & )
```

The redirections close `stdin`, and reopen `stdout` and `stderr`; the `nohup` stops HUP reaching the process when the owning process exits (I realise that the `2>&1` is somewhat redundant, since the `nohup` does something like this anyway); and the backgrounding within the subshell is the double-fork which means that the `./script.sh` process's parent has exited while it's still running, so it acquires the init process as its parent.

That doesn't *completely* work, however, because when I exit the shell from which I've invoked this (typically, of course, I'm doing this on a remote machine), it doesn't exit cleanly.  I can do `^C` to exit, and this is OK – the process does carry on in the background as intended.  However I can't work out what is/isn't happening to require the `^C`, and that's annoying me.

The actions above seem to tick most of the boxes in the [unix FAQ](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/programmer/faq/) (question 1.7), *except* that I'm not doing anything to detach this process from a controlling terminal, or to make it a session leader.  The setsid(2) call exists on FreeBSD, but not the `setsid` command; nor, as far as I can see, is there an obvious substitute for that command.  The same is true on macOS, of course.

So, the questions are:

- Is there a differently-named caller of `setsid` on this platform, that I'm missing?
- What, precisely, is happening when I exit the calling shell, that I'm killing with the `^C`?  Is there any way this could bite me?

Related questions (eg [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807688/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3430330/)) either answer a slightly different question, or assume the presence of the `setsid` command.

(This question has annoyed me for years, but because what I do here doesn't actually not work, I've never before got around to investigating, getting stumped, and asking about it).

Comment: What shell are you using? `csh` doesn't like your syntax and `sh` seems to exit without any problems at all.

Comment: It's bash and zsh (certainly not *csh), and I don't think it's anything complicated to do with a WM, since the time I notice this is when I'm (finishing) sshing somewhere. It's bound to be something subtle, though...

Comment: With `zsh` you may need to use `&!` instead of `&` to fully disown the job from the parent shell.

Comment: True, `&!` does ‘background and disown’, but disowning is just about removing from the job table, so is not subject to the job control operations (as I write this, I become aware I've a slightly vague idea of just what the ‘job table’ represents, and what removal from it means). Also the process backgrounded as above _does_ disappear from the job table.

Comment: There is a tiny (one C file) `setsid` program that I've been using on MacOSX (BSD-ish, also lacking a `setsid`) here:  https://github.com/jerrykuch/ersatz-setsid

Answer (score 2):

In FreeBSD, out of the box you could use [`daemon -- run detached from the controlling terminal`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=daemon&sektion=8). option `-r` could be useful:

```
-r       Supervise and restart the program after a one-second delay if it
         has been terminated.
```

You could also try a supervisor, for example [immortal](https://immortal.run/)  is available for both platforms:

```
pkg install immortal  # FreeBSD
brew install immortal # macOS
```

To daemonize your script and log (`stdout/stderr`) you could use:

```
immortal /path/to/your/script.sh -l /tmp/script.log
```

Or for more options, you could create a `my-service.yml` for example:

```
cmd: /path/to/script
cwd: /your/path
env:
    DEBUG: 1
    ENVIROMENT: production 
log:
    file: /tmp/app.log
stderr:
    file: /tmp/app-error.log
```

And then run it with `immortal -c my-service.yml`

More examples can be found here: https://immortal.run/post/examples

If just want to use `nohup` and save the `stdout` & `stderr` into a file, you could add this to your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec 2>&1

...
```

Check more about `exec 2>&1` in this answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/13088401/1135424

And then simply call `nohup /your/script.sh &` and check the file `nohup.out`, from the [man](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=nohup)

```
FILES
       nohup.out   The output file of the nohup execution if stan-
                   dard  output  is  a terminal and if the current
                   directory is writable.

       $HOME/nohup.out The output file of the nohup execution if stan-
                   dard  output  is  a terminal and if the current
                   directory is not writable.
```

Comment: Thanks for that, @nbari: the `daemon` command looks interesting, I can see some cases where that'll be useful, and looking at [the source](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/usr.sbin/daemon/daemon.c) I see it works by calling daemon(3). However the main motivation for my question was why the actions at the top – which do most of the job – aren't quite the full story.  It's a ‘what am I misunderstanding?’ question at heart.

Answer (score 0):

There's daemontools-encore by DJB for running any program as a daemon, including shell scripts. He has a whole tool set for running TCP servers, with rate limiting, and user isolation.